# change java process name

Tags: linux, java, process, start-stop-daemon

I am trying to change a java process name using the start-stop-daemon.
When running the process without the daemon I simply add to the script: "exec -a kuku"
And the java process name in the proc file is changed to kuku.
I read about the start-stop-daemon and didn't find a way to change the name, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`start-stop-daemon` has no functionality to do this. You will need to somehow call the libc function `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "name_here", 0, 0, 0)` from your java code to achieve this.

Comment: and if i want to change the name from the outside, without touching the java code? i want to use it as a black box

Comment: There is no way of doing that. You can only set the process name when calling `execve()` (which is what the bash `exec` function does) or from inside the process using that prctl.

Comment: isn't there a way to change a java process name from the outside?

Comment: No, there isn't any.